# Snapcraft custom LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: snapcraft

When building a snap package, the wrapper script automatically adds `$SNAP/usr/lib` to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

When building my package on docker, some libraries (in this case `liblapack` and `libblas`) are installed in subdirectories: `$SNAP/usr/lib/lapack`and `$SNAP/usr/lib/libblas` respectively.

Although all the dependencies are defined under `stage-packages` in my snapcraft.yaml, the paths above are not included in the wrapper script.

How can I force snapcraft to add the path to all the libraries to the wrapper script automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Snapcraft maintains a list of common library paths (e.g. `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/lib/<arch>`, etc.). If those directories exist, it will add them to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Think of how Ubuntu "finds" libs in such unpredictable paths as the one you mentioned: this is one of the reasons behind `/etc/ld.so.conf`. However, the typical way packages notify Ubuntu of new libraries is in a hook that is run after the Debian package is installed. In the case of Snapcraft, those hooks are never run-- stage-packages are simply unpacked. This means Snapcraft has no easy way of learning that the stage-package it just unpacked has a library in an unpredictable place.

While Snapcraft cannot currently help you automatically, you can definitely do this yourself, using one of two ways:

1. Create a wrapper script that sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/lapack` and then execs the binary you actually want to run. Then use that wrapper script in your `apps` section.
2. Make use of the new and [as yet undocumented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1666745) `environment` keyword, like this:

   ```
   apps:
     my-app:
       command: my-binary
       environment:
         LD_LIBRARY_PATH: $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$SNAP/usr/lib/lapack
   ```

Comment: `environment` keyword seems like the way to go for now, thanks @Kyle